# excel - Loop through worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have never used Marcos in Excel before only in Access. What I want to do is loop through the worksheet and where column X and Y are not null extract the information into a new worksheet. But row Y may have more than 1 value and I would like to create a new record for each value in Y with X. each value is separated by a comma.

[image]

The result I would Like is

a      C3

a      C4

b      C6

b      C7

b      C10

And so on

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Extract()
'
' Extract Macro
'
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook
Dim r As Integer
Dim Regex
Dim Match
Dim text
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("New")
Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Regex.Patten = """[^""]*""|[^,]*"
Regex.Global = True




j = 0
For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WkSht.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        For r = 1 To 1000
          If WkSht.Rows(r, B).Value <> "" & WkSht.Rows(r, G).Value <> "" Then
          text = WkSht.Rows(r, G).Value
           For Each Match In Regex.Execute(text)
           myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = WkSht.Cells(r, B)
           myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = Match
           j = j + 1
           Next Match
           Exit For
           End If
           r = r + 1
           Next r
           Exit For
           End If
           Next WkSht



End Sub
```

Im unable to get this to run, I think my syntax is wrong for the regex, iv only ever used it in c#, Is this the best option for what I am trying to achieve, any help would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: what error message are you getting? Start by changing `Regex.Patter` to `Regex.Pattern` then get back to us with the explicit error message

Comment: I think you would find it easier if you add a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** library (on the *Tools>References* menu in the VB Editor*. Then you can declare `Dim Regex as RegExp` and use `Set Regex = New RegExp`. This will give you **Intellisense** which will help you code corerctly. Also, in Tools>Options Editor tab, check all the boxes like `Require Variable declaration` and `Auto List Members`

Comment: You want better solution? Use Notepad++ and record macro to replace `,` with newline character `\n` and just play that macro, after that paste it in excel or import to excel via txt file and sort if you need it.

Comment: @Philip I'm getting a 1004 error on the " If WkSht.Rows(r, B).Value " line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix the 1004 error, change

`Rows(r, B).Value`

to

`Range(r, B).Value`

the Rows property only takes a single index, you are trying to test a cell, so muct use either the **Range** or **Cell** object.

also to make programming with RegEx easier, add a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library**:

on the Tools>References menu in the VB Editor.

Then you can declare 
`Dim Regex as RegExp` and use `Set Regex = New RegExp`

This will give you Intellisense which will help you code corerctly.

For a tutorial in using Regular expressions from Excel vba, see

- [MacroStash: Regular Expression Tutorial for Excel VBA](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/)
- [Regular Expressions Website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Also, the in Tools>Options **Editor** tab, check all the boxes like *Require Variable* declaration and *Auto List Members*

Comment: `Range(r, B).Value` to `Range(r, B).Value?` probably misspelled

Comment: I still get the 1004 error when I change the .Rows to .Range , Except this time it says Method "Range" of object _WorkSheet failed ? Any Idea ?

Comment: Still no joy :( got this error now  Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed !

Comment: when it stops, check the values of the variables **R** and **B** to ensure they are greater than zero

Comment: R comes up as 6 but B comes up as empty, B is the second row in my worksheet am I referencing it wrong ?

Comment: yes, in your code B is not set anywhere before you refrence it in your test. So you either need a loop with B through rows, or set it `B=2`